How to extend eslint config when using yarn workspaces
I have yarn workspaces in my repository in packages directory with 3 packages: shared and app-1, app-2.
In shared package i have .eslintrc.js config file with following rules:
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true,
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    // other rules
}

and in app-1 & app-2 i have .eslintrc.js which extends the config above like so:
module.exports = {
    extends: ["@superapp/shared/.eslintrc.js"],
};

and this does not work. And this does not work either
module.exports = {
    extends: ["@superapp/shared"],
};

I m starting to assume that it is not even possible to extend eslint config unless config is published to npm.

Legacy config already cascades, why not just hoist the shared one?

I have tsconfig.json per package, does not seem like a good idea to have shared eslint config in this case @jonrsharpe

Then why not use a relative path?

@jonrsharpe using relative path does not work as well
